# Javascript invalid date first time

Tags: javascript, debugging, datetime-format

I have the following code. When the code runs the first time, it creates an invalid at the third line. When I debug the code, I found that the value of `rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime` is: **1385433554848**. 
When I put this number in *jsfiddle.net* and run the code, it creates the date object fine. Therefore, I am confused what's happening here. Am I missing something while debugging the code? 
I thank you for your time and effort in answering my question.

```
_getLastUpdated: function(rowObj) {
    if(rowObj && rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime) {
        var lastUpdated = new Date(parseInt(rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime, 10)); //this line gives invalid date the first time it runs
        lastUpdated.setMilliseconds(lastUpdated.getMilliseconds() + utils.Utils.instance().getServerTimeDifference(lastUpdated));
        var locale = utils.Utils.instance().getLocale();
        var dateFormatString = utils.Utils.instance().getLocaleDateString(locale)+" hh:MM:ss TT";
        var dateString = utils.Utils.instance().dateFormat(lastUpdated,dateFormatString);               
        return dateString;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: What does it output to the console when you put: `console.log(parseInt(rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime, 10));`?

Comment: take the `parseInt()` out and check. That is, `new Date(rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime);`

Comment: So, did that work or what? Trying to help.

Comment: There's only one solution to this, if the date is invalid, the value you're passing isn't what you think it is, and the only way to see what it really is, is to follow @JohnKurlak advice and console log it.

Comment: Can you `console.log(typeof rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime)` that should give us better info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these tips. I am working on it. It's just that the domain went down, so I am recreating the environment. I'll post an update soon with all the answers to the suggestions.

Comment: I did the prescribed debugging, and this is what I get: console.log(typeof rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime); returns number. console.log(parseInt(rowObj.$$lastModifiedTime, 10)); outputs: 1385579260446. Finally, I also tried removing parseInt as rdodev mentioned, but it still says invalid date.

Comment: @Dan That's really odd. Are you sure the error is there and not elsewhere in that method? I cannot replicate it locally.

Comment: does this code run on a mobile phone? i had a similar issue with dates in Phonegap. It worked after I converted milliseconds to seconds.

Comment: A quick update - the bug was in getServerTimeDifference(lastUpdated), it returned an object rather than a number. This entire piece of js is a dynamic script, so I would go back from a later function call dateFormat() into _getLastUpdated(). The date was created fine, but it was corrupted while doing the milliseconds addition. However, in the debugger,  when I would go back from dateFormat() function call up in _getLastUpdated(), it showed me the lastUpdated object corrupted even at it's time of creation. Thanks all once again for taking out time and looking into it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the bug was in getServerTimeDifference(lastUpdated), it returned an object rather than a number. This entire piece of js is a dynamic script, so I would go back from a later function call dateFormat() into _getLastUpdated(). The date was created fine, but it was corrupted while doing the milliseconds addition. However, in the debugger, when I would go back from dateFormat() function call up in _getLastUpdated(), it showed me the lastUpdated object corrupted even at it's time of creation.